# AWS API Gateway - Step Function Integration, 500 Error on Success

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

I have an API Gateway, integrated to a Step Function, inside a VPC.

When I hit the endpoint the step function is successfully executing, but it's still replying with:

```
500 Internal Server Error
{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

Everything is setup in terraform, have tried setting up a response in terraform and on the console but both aren't working.

screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/Kikasjb.png

note, looked at this post: [AWS API Gateway - Lambda - Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57499316/aws-api-gateway-lambda-internal-server-error)

It's similar but there the reply is around a lambda returning a value, but this step function is asynchronous so not sure how something gets send back here. Thanks!

Comment: is you setup as following? Api gateway `triggers` step function `triggers` lambda function `returns response` to step function `returns response` to API gateway?

Comment: Hi Chetan, not setup that way. The step function is itself async and contains multiple lambdas. So not sure how the step function would return something to the api gateway?

Comment: I will be helpful if you can describe the integration in the question using some diagram or block...  If the step function needs a response from the lambda function then why use async? why not call the function and wait for it to complete? or why not call the API gateway from the lambda function itself?

Comment: Hi, I don't need the response from step function, just to return a 200 OK when it's triggered. I figured out my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered my issue was that when settings in the API Gateway in the console I have to redeploy the API gateway before being able to test the change.